# speedup computation?

Tags: programming-languages, statistics, computer-science

let's say i have an algorithm A run on two machines X and Y. So below is the result

```
   Machine    Elapsed time(sec)
      X            20
      Y            10
```

how do you express the speedup? ... thanks!

Comment: I think you need to give more information here. I'm still not even sure what the question is, precisely.

Comment: Suppose someone in New York earns $50K whilst someone in London earns $60K, what can you say about the wages in each city. Answer - not very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 / 10 = 2, subtract 1 (base), multiply by 100 and you have a 100% speed-up on machine X.

Comment: 20/10 = 2, last time I checked :)

Comment: @Prasad Grr, you know how many times I make stupid errors on trivial questions? :-/ Will fix.